# UILabel in UITableViewCell's accessoryview is out of bound only in iOS13

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, ios13, accessoryview

I have an app that show some text in a UIlabel attached in UITableviewCell's AccessoryView.

Everything works fine for years till iOS13, nothing changed but UILabel and text seem out of bound. iOS12 and below do not have similar problem.

I checked online, some guys said UIButton had same issue which fixed in iOS13.1.

Please check the screenshots for iOS12.4 and iOS13.1

Thanks in advance!

[image: iOS12.4]

[image: iOS13.1]

Comment: This really isn't how `accessoryView` should be used. It would be better to create a custom cell that adds the label to the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: Oops，maybe I do misused accessoryView. Thanks for let me know, if the problem can't be solved, I would try the custom cell instead. thank you!